# Перестали отображаться настройки уведомлений в приложении ios

Tags: ios

Хронология событий.

1) Сделана тестовая версия, установлена через testflight, уведомления с google firebase работают. Если перейти в настройки приложения, можно включить или выключить уведомления, development и distribution сертификаты сгенерированы и загружены на firebase.

2) Приложение загружено на store, c этим же пакетом.

3) После установки с App Store, уведомления не работают и в настройках отсутствуют.

4) После удаления приложения и повторной загрузки с testflight той же версии, что до этого работала - уведомления не работают и в настройках отсутствуют. В тестировании принимало участие два телефона, одинаковый результат.

т.е вот этого окна нету

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В X-code 8.2.1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то же и на developer.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь что в сертификатах все в порядке и срок действия профайлов и ключей не истек:
[image: Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles]